# Use of logical operators AND OR when comparing conditionals

Tags: perl, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am facing some doubts about the use (and return values I guess) of the logical operators &&, and, ||, or.

```
$number = 5; 
$numberA = 5;
$numberB = 1;

$string = "x"; 
$stringA = "x";
$stringB = "y";

If two numbers are compared:
$x=5;   
if ( $x == $number ) { print '$x == $number', "\n"; }


If two strings are compared:
$x="x";
if ( $x eq $string ) { print '$x eq $string', "\n"; }
```

But I'm not sure what is the best way to evaluate two numbers/strings to a number/string. Is this correct?

```
$x=5; $y=5;
if ( ($x && $y) == $number ) { print '($x && $y) == $number', "\n"; }


$x="x"; $y="x";
if ( ($x and $y) eq $string ) { print '($x and $y) eq $string', "\n"; }
```

And what is the rule when two logicals are evaluated in the same condition? Should the conditions itself be compared as numbers (&&,||) or strings (and,or)?

```
$x=5; $y=1;
if ( ($x == $numberA) && ($y == $numberB) ) { print '&& or and here?', "\n"; }

$x="x"; $y="y";
if ( ($x eq $stringA) and ($y eq $stringB) ) { print 'and or or here?', "\n"; }
```

Comment: What is (5 && 5) to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
( $foo && $bar ) == $baz
```

does not do what you think it does; it first evaluates the && operation, getting the value of `$foo` if `$foo` is true and otherwise getting the value of `$bar`, then compares that to `$baz`.  You need to explicitly spell it out as `$foo == $baz && $bar == $baz` to test both.

If you have many values (preferably in an array, not a bunch of separate variables), grep can be useful:

```
if ( 2 == grep $_ == $baz, $foo, $bar ) {
```

List::MoreUtils provides a convenient `all` method, too:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'all';
if ( all { $_ == $baz } $foo, $bar ) {
```

`and`/`or` and `&&`/`||` are not string or numeric operators; the alphabetic ones function exactly the same as the equivalent symbolic ones.  The only difference is that they have different precedence; `&&`/`||` have a higher precedence, such that they are useful *within* an expression; `and`/`or` have a lower precedence, such that they are useful for flow control between what are essentially different expressions.  Some examples:

```
my $x = $y || 'default_value';
```

equivalent to:

```
my $x = ( $y || 'default_value' );
```

vs.

```
my @a = get_lines() or die "expected some lines!";
```

equivalent to:

```
( my @a = get_lines() ) or die "expected some lines!";
```

Comment: Great answer. I was looking for this type of explanation.